# Excel VBA Find.Row returning value plus 1268

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have set up a userform that searches a worksheet for data from the 1st field, and successfully finds it. Two other fields are populated with data from the row found from searching. I want to be able to write data in the same row from a 4th field. However, the same working search code returns a row number that's 1268 rows off in a different sub.

Edit: Inserted entire userform code, with new search as described in BigBen's response. Here's an [image of the userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F75k.png) to see the user side. I appreciate assistance, and I hear your groans for my lack of training in VBA.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Reset buttons to white
    button_search_inactive.Visible = True
    button_save_inactive.Visible = True

    'Make code operate faster
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    'Declare all default variables
    Dim allTransactionData As Worksheet
    Dim locationNew As String
    Dim bottle As String
    Dim locationFormer As String
    Dim bottleFormer As String

    'Assign default values to variables
    Set allTransactionData = Worksheets("Transactions")
    locationNew = ""
    bottle = ""
    bottleFormer = "^ Search Bottle"
    locationFormer = ""

    'Set default form view
    With Me
        .Height = 205
        .Width = 181
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .StartUpPosition = 2
        .field_locationFormer.Value = locationFormer
        .field_bottle = bottleFormer
        .field_search = bottle
        .field_location = locationNew

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub button_search_active_Click()

    With Me
        'Validates search entry
        If .field_search.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Please enter a bottle number.")
        Else
            'Set query
            bottle = .field_search.Value
            Set allTransactionData = Worksheets("Transactions")

            'Find most recent transaction for relevant bottle number
            With allTransactionData
                Dim foundRng As Range
                Set foundRng = .Columns("C:C").Find(What:=bottle, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then

                    'Pull the former container location
                    bottleFormer = bottle
                    locationFormer = allTransactionData.Cells(foundRng.Row, 6)
                Else

                    'Inform user there are no transactions under query
                    bottle = "No Transactions"
                    locationFormer = "Found."

                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With

    With Me

        'Fill form fields with search results
        .field_bottle = bottle
        .field_locationFormer = locationFormer

        'Set focus to new location
        .field_location.SetFocus


    End With
End Sub

Private Sub button_save_active_Click()

    With Me
        'Validate that search has been performed
        If .field_search.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Search for a bottle number first.")
        Else
            'Validates if bottle was found
            If .field_locationFormer.Value = "Found." Then
                MsgBox ("Search must yield a bottle result before you can modify a location.")
            Else
                'Validates contents in location field
                If .field_location.Value = "" Then
                    MsgBox ("Please enter a location.")
                Else

                    '               Issue with value + 1268


                    'Enter the location

                    Set allTransactionData = Worksheets("Transactions")

                    With allTransactionData
                        Dim foundRng As Range
                        Set foundRng = .Columns("C:C").Find(What:=bottle, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                        If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
                            .Cells(foundRng.Row, 11).Value = Me.field_location.Value
                        End If
                    End With
                    'Empty fields for next use
                    With Me
                        locationNew = ""
                        bottle = ""
                        bottleFormer = "^ Search Bottle"
                        locationFormer = ""
                        .field_locationFormer.Value = locationFormer
                        .field_bottle = bottleFormer
                        .field_search = bottle
                        .field_location = locationNew
                        'Set focus to search field
                        .field_search.SetFocus
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub button_search_inactive_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'Add Color to Search Button
    button_search_inactive.Visible = False
    button_save_inactive.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub button_save_inactive_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'Add Color to Save Button
    button_save_inactive.Visible = False
    button_search_inactive.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'Reset buttons to white

    button_search_inactive.Visible = True
    button_save_inactive.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub frame_current_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    button_search_inactive.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub frame_new_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    button_save_inactive.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

User Search: *Bottle 1*

*Bottle 1* found in row 2, below header. Rows 3 and on are empty.

releRow should equal 1, but equals 1269 instead. As a result, (1269,10) becomes the selection, while I want (1,10). I tried simple subtraction (`releRow = releRow - 1268`) with little expectation, and it didn't solve the issue.

Thanks in advance, this is my first post.

Comment: `releRow` should be a `Long`, or you run the risk of overflow.  Where are you assigning a value to `bottle` ?

Comment: What does this give you ?  `Debug.Print Worksheets("Transactions").Range("C1269").Formula`

Comment: Side note: check out this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to clean up your indentation a bit, and also add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: @Tim Williams ```bottle``` is assigned 8 lines after ```Private Sub button_search_active_Click()```. The ```Debug...``` doesn't provide an output. Thanks for the tool @BigBen

Comment: `Application.Calculation = xlManual` - you never reset this.  Also why run `Find()` with `LookIn:=xlFormulas` instead of `xlValues`  ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I reset to ```xlAutomatic``` on the sixth line from the bottom. As for ```xlFormulas```, I thought I had read a reason to use it instead of ```xlValues``` for my situation somewhere on MS's XlFindLookIn enumerations page, but that's not the case. The code appears to run the same with changing to ```xlValues```.

Comment: You're missing something.  I've never seen Find() locate a value where it isn't present.

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, that should reveal some issues. Specifically, `bottle` in `button_save_active_Click()` is an undeclared local Variant and has no connection to the local String called `bottle` declared in `UserForm_Initialize()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `Select`, and you are not actually referencing the `With allTransactionData`. Note the period `.` needed in front of `Columns("C:C")`.

```
With allTransactionData
    Dim foundRng as Range
    Set foundRng = .Columns("C:C").Find(What:=bottle, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
         .Cells(foundRng.Row, 10).Value = Me.field_location.Value
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me clean up. I didn't know that ```[range].Row``` was a thing. However, data is still written in (1269,10) and I've no idea why.

Comment: What is `bottle`? What happens when  you find it manually? Also remove the parens around bottle (edited my post already)

Comment: ```bottle``` is the value stored from the userform's search field. ```bottle``` will always be in column C. When I manually search for *Bottle 1* with Ctrl+F, it finds it in row 2, below the worksheet header. The worksheet is blank from rows 3 and on.

Comment: It's defined in ```Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()``` with ```Dim bottle As String```. I can post an answer with the entire userform code if that helps. I'm fine with the internet knowing I just started VBA :)

Comment: If you have additional code, edit your question instead of posting an update in the answer space.

Comment: I edited my question. @SJR the value is assigned when the user clicks the search button.

Comment: OK, but is the search term found more than once in column C? And please reply to Tim's question above.

Comment: @SJR The search term would be found multiple times in theory. The worksheet is acting as a database, and I'm using ```xlPrevious``` in ```Find``` because I want the most recent transaction, However, the search term is found only once currently.